# How to use ${maven.build.timestamp} in a custom Maven plug-in?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I want to access the Maven build timestamp in my custom Maven plug-in. Therefore, I try to use the special variable [`maven.build.timestamp`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables) :

> `maven.build.timestamp`  The timestamp that denotes the start of the build. *Since Maven 2.1.0-M1*

with [`Parameter#defaultValue`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Parameter.html#defaultValue()):

> parameter default value, eventually containing `${...}` expressions which will be interpreted at inject time: see  PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.

but I get always the value `null`. I tried it with type `Date` and with type `String`.

**Java code:**

```java
@Mojo(name = "test", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES)
public class TestMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${maven.build.timestamp}", readonly = true)
    private Date timestampDate;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${maven.build.timestamp}", readonly = true)
    private String timestampString;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        getLog().error("timestampDate: " + timestampDate);
        getLog().error("timestampString: " + timestampString);
    }
}
```

**Plug-in configuration:**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
     <artifactId>test-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.12</version>
</plugin>
```

**Log:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- test-maven-plugin:0.0.12:test (default-cli) @ test               ---
[ERROR] timestampDate: null
[ERROR] timestampString: null
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.799 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-21T14:37:20+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/223M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Environment:**

- Java 8
- embedded Maven 3.3.3

Why is the special variable not resolved in my custom Maven plug-in?

Answer (score 2):

I found two workarounds.

- `maven.build.timestamp` in plug-in configuration

  **Java code:**

  ```java
  @Mojo(name = "test", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES)
  public class TestMojo extends AbstractMojo {

      @Parameter
      private String timestamp;

      @Override
      public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
          getLog().error("timestamp: " + timestamp);
      }
  }
  ```

  **Plug-in configuration:**

  ```xml
  <plugin>
       <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
       <artifactId>test-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.12</version>
       <configuration>
           <timestampString>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestampString>
       </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```

  **Disadvantage:**

  The boiler plate code in the configuration.
- `session.request.startTime` as default value

  **Java code:**

  ```java
  @Mojo(name = "test", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES)
  public class TestMojo extends AbstractMojo {

      @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session.request.startTime}", readonly = true)
      private Date timestamp;

      @Override
      public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
          getLog().error("timestamp: " + timestamp);
      }
  }
  ```

  **Plug-in configuration:**

  ```xml
  <plugin>
       <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
       <artifactId>test-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.12</version>
  </plugin>
  ```

  **Disadvantage:**

  I'm not sure, that the value of `session.request.startTime` is always the same as `maven.build.timestamp`. And the format defined with [`maven.build.timestamp.format`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables) is not automatically used.